# Why does linking to just the domain name of a website have different OG properties than linking domain/index.php?

Tags: php, html, facebook-opengraph

When I link my website on Facebook, `www.example.com/`, it doesnt show the same content as it does when I link `www.example.com/index.php`. In fact, it is so wrong that when no specific page is entered, just the domain name, the website agency's og content appears instead of whats on my index page. How can I make it so that entering just the domain name mirrors `index.php`'s OG tags?

```
<meta property="og:title" content="website title">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:description" content="my website description">
<meta name="og:title" content="website title">
<meta property=”og:url” content=”http://www.example.com/index.php” />
<meta name=”og:url” content=”http://www.example.com/index.php” />
<meta name="og:type" content="website">
<meta name="og:description" content="my website description">
```

Comment: Why using same meta's twice ? Try this andyou can include description is well `<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video.movie" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg" />`

Comment: Are you using the same domain names, please doublecheck?

Comment: You might want to look at the raw responses, and check headers etc for the two URLs.  We don't know about your hosting/web server configuration.  If you are using Apache you might want to check the DirectoryIndex value.  It may be that say index.html is preferred over index.php.  Check if other files exist in your web root.  The important thing to note here, is that omitting index.php, does not necessarily present the same resource - it depends on server and configuration.